# Play two embedded youtube videos synchronized

Tags: php, javascript, video, youtube

I would like to add on the webpage two embedded youtube videos: one with song clip (LEFT) and the other with song lyrics or translation(RIGHT). The RIGHT video is made by me, so if I play them offline in two windows the lyrics are synchronized with clip. The videos are uploaded then to youtube.

The question is: how can I "join" these two videos online, so user will have just one play/pause button, and if he jumps for example to 0:12 - both videos jump to 0:12. Is that possible?

I can't make a one video with both clip and lyrics, as might someone suggest. The RIGHT video with lyrics can be in different languages, while the song clip is the same.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the same audio with several lyrics videos?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with xuggler. http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/

You would need some bits on the server to do the work and stream the results.

Xuggler is quite fast assuming you have all the videos available at request time. If you are forced to dl them from YouTube and then combine them it might get more exciting.

Comment: That's for java, isn't it? (might still be relevant if OP is willing to write java code)

Comment: Yes. Something similar might be available via FFMPEG too. There would still be some server side manipulation but it might be more language agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

**as of now an incomplete answer. to be completed when plugin described is built.**

You could build this with [Acorn](https://acorn.athena.ai/), a media remixing javascript library.

The capabilities to do this (side-by-side videos) is not there yet out of the box (I've added [an issue](https://github.com/athenalabs/acorn-player/issues/112) to the [acorn-player](https://github.com/athenalabs/acorn-player) repository).

All that needs to be done is build a `shell` (`acorn-player` plugin) that embeds two pieces of media side by side, and let acorn do the youtube api play-syncing heavy lifting.